# Java Web enterprise Application "Client"

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, client, application-server

At my current work, we are redesigning the entire core application which is basically `springMVC`, `ejb3`, `SpringF`, `AJAX`, etc.

Our clients are like 60, that uses the same application depending on the acquired license.

We are thinking to develop an application that can be simply installed locally on their places.

Something like: `setup.exe` which will install the `Application Server`, install the EAR and use a light weight database, something like `Derby`.

I have few questions:

1. Have you done something like that? how is your app working?
2. Which application server did you use?
3. How did you coded the auto update service?
4. And Licenses?

Also we are planning to provide "modules" via the same application client, that will have some JSP and WebServices consumer. For example:

When acquired the Transfer Module, the webservice will provide something like:

```
<module>
  <name>Transfer</name>
  <parameters>
    <parameter type="text">Name</parameter>
    <parameter type="number">account</parameter>
    <parameter type="currency">DO</parameter>
    <parameter type="number">To Account</parameter>
    <parameter type="text">Description</parameter>
  </parameters>
</module>
```

That will render, first a dynamic JSP page, and base on that validated and then sent to a webservice.

1. That looks like a good job? or practice for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of so many reasons to not to do this. But I am sure you have analyzed your requirements and have come up with such a need.

have few questions:

- Have you done something like that?

  NO

  how is your app working?

  ```
       We did have something similar, but not on an per client machine
  ```

  basis because of system hardware requirements in the first place but it was more like a client server. Like an ATM machine with a server to talk to the main banking server.

  Which application server did you use?

  - Preferably JBOSS application server or Tomcat with light configuration.

    How did you coded the auto update service?

  On server startup you could always download the jar and copy it to a place if needed.
     And Licenses?

  Several strategies including downloading pre-built ears or specific license keys.

Comment: nice, I would like to hear some of your many reasons to not to do this... Thanks!

Comment: Distributing setup.exe, providing bug & security fixes and making sure all clients are getting updated, client server hardware specs for installing your app, migrating data to newer versions of product when the clients want to move to a newer product version, managing the newer migrations. A multi tenant design would be better, though that has it's own challenges. These are more technical / delivery implementation issues, does not pertain to business.